# check if the file is existing or not using PAF

Tags: ipaf, paceautomationframework

I am looking to validate a file is existing or not in a folder using pace Automation Framework?
Is any Tag is there to perform this action?

Answer (score 0):

The variable 'Status' returns a boolean value as true/false. Using tag we can validate the value of the variable.